# Sending Email alert in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

Hi would like to send an email alert after checking the result of a query which will return the numbers of rows in a table. Does anyone have any ideas how I could do this in SQL Server 2000 in 2005 I would use a maintenence plan but not sure how in 2000?

Answer (score 1):

I did this a few years ago - hastily adapted from a MS Knowledgebase article. I changed the params to be hardcoded variables. I've removed the identifying servernames/email addresses etc etc from here but you should be able to figure it out!

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SendSuccessMail]
--Adapted from a Microsoft KnowledgeBase article, Jan 16th 2006.

```
--   @From varchar(100) ,
 --  @To varchar(100) ,
  -- @Subject varchar(100)=" ",
   --@Body varchar(4000) =" "
/*********************************************************************

This stored procedure takes the parameters and sends an e-mail.
All the mail configurations are hard-coded in the stored procedure.
Comments are added to the stored procedure where necessary.
References to the CDOSYS objects are at the following MSDN Web site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_messaging.asp

***********************************************************************/
   AS
   Declare @From varchar(100) --origninally passed as parameter above. We want to hard-code it.
   Declare @To varchar(100) --origninally passed as parameter above. We want to hard-code it.
   Declare @Subject varchar(100) --origninally passed as parameter above. We want to hard-code it.
   Declare @Body varchar(4000) --origninally passed as parameter above. We want to hard-code it.
   Declare @iMsg int
   Declare @hr int
   Declare @source varchar(255)
   Declare @description varchar(500)
   Declare @output varchar(1000)
   Set @From = 'abc@xyz.com'
   Set @To = 'xyz@abc.com'
   Set @Subject = 'Whatever Subject You Want'
   Set @Body = 'Some useful text'


--************* Create the CDO.Message Object ************************
   EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'CDO.Message', @iMsg OUT
   IF @hr <>0 BEGIN
print 'sp_OACreate failed'
   END

--***************Configuring the Message Object ******************
-- This is to configure a remote SMTP server.
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cdosys/html/_cdosys_schema_configuration_sendusing.asp
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing").Value','2'
-- This is to configure the Server Name or IP address.
-- Replace MailServerName by the name or IP of your SMTP Server.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").Value', 'mail.xxxxxxxxxx.com'
-- Save the configurations to the message object.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Configuration.Fields.Update', null
-- Set the e-mail parameters.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'To', @To
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'From', @From
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Subject', @Subject
-- If you are using HTML e-mail, use 'HTMLBody' instead of 'TextBody'.
   EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'TextBody', @Body
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Send', NULL
   IF @hr <>0
     BEGIN
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetErrorInfo NULL, @source OUT, @description OUT
       IF @hr = 0
         BEGIN
           SELECT @output = '  Source: ' + @source
           PRINT  @output
           SELECT @output = '  Description: ' + @description
           PRINT  @output
         END

     END

-- Do some error handling after each step if you have to.
-- Clean up the objects created.
    send_cdosysmail_cleanup:
If (@iMsg IS NOT NULL) -- if @iMsg is NOT NULL then destroy it
BEGIN
    EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @iMsg

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT ' sp_OADestroy skipped because @iMsg is NULL.'

        RETURN
END
```

GO

Answer (score 0):

Because SQLMail is so useless for real world usage (MAPI, etc), we ended up using [SQLAnswersMail](http://www.sqlanswers.com/) which is very powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps CDOSYS will serve your needs, check the links below

- [Configuring SQL Server 2000
  Notification with CDOSys](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SQL2000CDOSysMail&referringTitle=DiskSpaceMon)
- [How to send e-mail without using SQL Mail in SQL Server?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312839)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xp_smtp_sendmail
```

[Link](http://www.sqldev.net/xp/xpsmtp.htm)

http://www.sqldev.net/xp/xpsmtp.htm

I've used it before in production and it works great.